# 10.9 Contacts.app doesn’t sync one contacts card with iCloud

Tags: icloud, macos, contacts

Contacts.app in 10.9 says "Some server contacts could not be copied to this address book."

iCloud.com shows 499 contacts
iOS shows 499 contacts
10.9 shows 498 contacts

is there a way to fix this or find this missing contact?

Comment: Have you tried disabling contact sync from iCloud panel in sys preferences and enabling it back?